# How to generate future forecasts with dates using auto.arima in R?

Tags: r, time-series

i would like to generate forecasts using auto.arima however i dont see future dates populated. How can i get future forecasts with date. I am having weekly data, want to generate forecasts upto Dec 2020

i am using forecast package in R

```
fit <- auto.arima(zoo_ts)

fcast <- forecast(fit, h=83)
```

Need weekly forecast from july 2019 with dates having weekly interval. I am not providing any data. Can anyone share how to do it will be great

Comment: Here is a great [source](https://otexts.com/fpp2/) to get you started, and advanced on forecasting

Comment: Thanks, but i cannot figure out how to generate forecasts with date. Eg i have actual up to June 2019 . But ARIMA generates forecasts from July 2019 , it doesnt show any dates. I want dates as well along with forecasts

Answer (score 0):

The `forecast` package uses `ts` objects, which are not great for weekly data. The time index is stored numerically in terms of years. So 2019.5385 means week 28 of 2019 (as 28/52 = 0.5385).

An alternative is to use the `fable` and `tsibble` packages. Here is an example using weekly data.

```r
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(fpp3) # For the data

# Fit the model
fit <- us_gasoline %>% model(arima = ARIMA(Barrels))
# Produce forecasts
fcast <- forecast(fit, h = 83)
fcast
#> # A fable: 83 x 4 [1W]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>    .model     Week Barrels .distribution
#>    <chr>    <week>   <dbl> <dist>       
#>  1 arima  2017 W04    8.30 N(8.3, 0.072)
#>  2 arima  2017 W05    8.44 N(8.4, 0.077)
#>  3 arima  2017 W06    8.53 N(8.5, 0.082)
#>  4 arima  2017 W07    8.59 N(8.6, 0.086)
#>  5 arima  2017 W08    8.48 N(8.5, 0.091)
#>  6 arima  2017 W09    8.49 N(8.5, 0.096)
#>  7 arima  2017 W10    8.61 N(8.6, 0.101)
#>  8 arima  2017 W11    8.52 N(8.5, 0.106)
#>  9 arima  2017 W12    8.58 N(8.6, 0.111)
#> 10 arima  2017 W13    8.47 N(8.5, 0.115)
#> # … with 73 more rows
```

The time index is stored in weeks here. This can be converted to a date using `as.Date`:

```r
# Convert weekly index to a date
fcast %>% mutate(date = as.Date(Week))
#> # A fable: 83 x 5 [1W]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>    .model     Week Barrels .distribution date      
#>    <chr>    <week>   <dbl> <dist>        <date>    
#>  1 arima  2017 W04    8.30 N(8.3, 0.072) 2017-01-23
#>  2 arima  2017 W05    8.44 N(8.4, 0.077) 2017-01-30
#>  3 arima  2017 W06    8.53 N(8.5, 0.082) 2017-02-06
#>  4 arima  2017 W07    8.59 N(8.6, 0.086) 2017-02-13
#>  5 arima  2017 W08    8.48 N(8.5, 0.091) 2017-02-20
#>  6 arima  2017 W09    8.49 N(8.5, 0.096) 2017-02-27
#>  7 arima  2017 W10    8.61 N(8.6, 0.101) 2017-03-06
#>  8 arima  2017 W11    8.52 N(8.5, 0.106) 2017-03-13
#>  9 arima  2017 W12    8.58 N(8.6, 0.111) 2017-03-20
#> 10 arima  2017 W13    8.47 N(8.5, 0.115) 2017-03-27
#> # … with 73 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks , but is there any other way ? As i am having issues installing fable package - I read on github there are some changes , so tried fablelite still it says 'Lazy loading failed' . Moreover after i generate the forecast using auto.arima though my actual are from 2018 oct to 2019 june. Point forecasts are generated from 2018(2018.904) am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Install fable from cran. If you want to use forecast, you just have to translate the date as I explained. It sounds like you have not set the ts attributes correctly. If you want any more help you need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: You'll need to uninstall the dev version of the fablelite package. The appropriate CRAN package that replaces fablelite is fabletools.